# How to return a cell reference from a formula

Tags: excel

I have a formula which returns the first non-zero value in a row - the numbers will fill up as the year goes on.

`1 2 3 _ _ _`

`=IFERROR(LOOKUP(1E+100,H21:S21),"")`

How do I find the cell reference of this value the LOOKUP returns - without using MATCH as the value isn't necessarily unique?
What I want is the same cell but 51 rows down, or so.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`Match()` is probably the right way to go.

```
=OFFSET(H21, 50, MATCH(1E+100,H21:S21,-1)-1)
```

The last parameter of `Match()`, when set to `-1` says to find the first value in the range (`H21:S21`) that is `greater than` the lookup value (`1E+100`), which is what I think you are doing here with `LOOKUP`

The `Offset()` goes down `50` rows and then we just subtract 1 from the result of `Match` to determine how many columns to move across.

If you just want the address of the item found by `Match()` you could use:

```
=ADDRESS(21, MATCH(10000,H21:S21,-1))
```

But I would imagine that `Offset()` probably gets you closer to your end game.